# Does Elend Venture ever identify his rescuer?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, the-final-empire

In *Mistborn: The Final Empire*, an assassination attempt against Elend Venture was stopped. His father, Straff Venture, dismissed these rumors:

> Some of the guards claim there was a third Mistborn, fighting the other two, but I doubt the reports - it wasn't one of ours.

It's conceivable that Vin could've revealed the truth, but canonically, does Elend ever discover the identity of the third Mistborn?

Comment: It has been awhile since I read the trilogy, but if it isn't stated explicitly at some point then I'm pretty sure he could have deduced it later on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're talking about

> Elend finding out that Shan Elariel tried to assassinate and Vin killed her

Then the following quote (The Hero of Ages chapter 28)

> "Plus, you’ve managed—in our short three years together—to kill not only my god, but my father, my brother, and my fiancée. That’s kind of like a homicidal hat trick" - Elend Venture

Answer (score -2):

I don't have hold of the books right now, but I'm pretty certain he found out in the books. 
(EDIT) Found a line off "The Coppermind" (wiki for the series) that seems to say he found out (it's rather ambiguous), "Elend was saved by Vin... He later discovered that she was in fact a skaa and tried to find her..." (http://coppermind.net/wiki/Elend_Venture)

Comment: Your answer boils down to, "Maybe. I think so." But without a source or even an actual certainty, this should really be a comment. Maybe you can find some sort of quote somewhere online that backs up your recollection which would make this a useful answer.